# How to change custom message in alert box

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to change custom message in alert box by using hostlistner when page refreshing in angular

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Am trying to change a custom message to alert message
I tried below code

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", 
["$event"]) 
unloadHandler(event:Event) {
let result = confirm("Changes you 
made may not be saved.");
if (result) {
}
event.returnValue = false; 
}
```

Comment: You're answering your own question with additional information. It would be prefferable for you to edit your original question with this so others can best answer it.